# How do you add a unique key to a Database.Persist model using the quasiquoter?

Tags: haskell, yesod, esqueleto

How do you build a unique key with two or more fields using the `persistLowerCase` quasiquoter?

When using [`Database.Persist`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-1.3.0.2) to create models for a simple website using guidance from the [Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent), the following error crops up:

```
Build FAILED
$PREFIX/App/Models.hs: line 42, column 18:
  Not in scope: data constructor `GroupSlug'
$PREFIX/App/Models.hs: line 43, column 19:
  Not in scope: data constructor `GroupName'
```

#### App/Models.hs

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-orphans #-}

module App.Models where

import           Data.Text                    (Text)
import           Database.Persist.TH

share [ mkPersist sqlSettings
      , mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Post
    group          GroupId
    postName       Text
    postSlug       Text
    period         Text
    content_en     Text
    content_pt     Text
    UniquePost     postSlug
    deriving Show
Group
    groupId      Int
    groupName    Text
    groupSlug    Text
    parent       GroupId
    UniqueGroup  groupId groupSlug
    deriving Show
|]
```

#### App/Handlers.hs

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module App.Handlers where

import           Database.Esqueleto
import           App.Models

groupQuery x =
    select $
    from $ \g -> do
    where_ (g ^. GroupSlug ==. val x)
    return $ g ^. GroupName
```

#### Versions:

- Haskell Platform 2013.2
- `Cabal` == 1.19.2
- `persistent` == 1.3.0.2
- [`scotty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty) == 0.6.2
- [`esqueleto`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-1.3.4.5/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html) == 1.3.4.5

Am I missing some extension or overlooking something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, data constructors that you're trying to use are actually called `GroupGroupSlug` and `GroupGroupName` (not just `GroupSlug` and `GroupName`). That is because the data type is generated by taking the entity name and joining it with the field name (with proper capitalisation). Try loading your source files with the `-ddump-splices` command-line parameter, and you should see it in the output somewhere.